# Prevent URL updating with scrollTop anchor links

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I have the following JS but I don't want the URL to be updated with the hash, how can I prevent this?

I want the scrollTop to work for both same page anchor links and when linking to an ID on a different page which is currently working correctly.

```
var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var target = $(this).attr("href");
   } else {
     var target = location.hash;
   }

$('html,body').animate(
{
 scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
 }, 2000, function()
 {
   location.hash = target;
 });

}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

if (location.hash){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
        jump();
    }, 0);
}else{
    $('html, body').show();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3D4k9/

Answer (score 0):

Add window.location.hash = '' to your jump function:

```
... //previous code

window.location.hash = ''

...
```

This will remove the hash from the url in the navigation bar

**EDIT**: Also, add 'return false' to the end of the jump function.
This should stop the event from propagating and changing the hash in the address bar

Comment: I tried, the fiddle and the hash isn't showing in the address bar. What's not functioning properly?